# Spin Connection derivation in dirac equation

Tags: dirac-equation, spinors

I'm learning about the spin connection, more specifically how it is derived in the dirac equation through this notes:

http://web.phys.ntnu.no/~mika/CPP/ch15.pdf

In the third page of the document it is mentioned that starting from the dirac equation and considering local lorentz transformatio a covariant derivative must be defined so that the lagrangian is invariant. I tried to derive this but I haven't been able. I will show my calculation below.

I start from the transformed lagrangian (the tilde means a transformed quantity, and $\nabla$ is the covariant derivative with the spin connection defined in the document):
$$\widetilde{\bar{\psi}} (i\gamma^a \widetilde{\nabla_a}-m)\psi = \psi^{\dagger}S^{\dagger}\gamma^0( i \gamma^a \Lambda^b_a \partial_b S + i\Lambda^b_a S\partial_b - S \omega_a S^{\dagger}S + iS\partial_a S^{\dagger}S-mS)\psi $$

Now the idea is to make the invariant lagrangian appear but im not abel to do it. Can someone help me?